# Google Fit App verification and OAuth 2.0 api limit

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-fit

I am using google fit API to read health user data only. For this do I need to verify my app in google app verification? And also is there any kind of limit for reading health data? Any help will be appreciated !!
Thank you.

Comment: Any application has users will need to be verified.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need the verification. I work on a similar app that only reads the Fit data, and even the read only scopes are marked as sensitive and thus require verification.

Regarding the reading of data, I do not know of any limitation.